# TortoiseSVN: Couldn't read Status line in VM

Tags: tortoisesvn

I encountered a weird problem in TorToiseSVN 1.6 in a Virtual Machine: I can't checkout files from any online source control system. One of the examples I have tested is:

```
http://codesmith.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

The error I got was

```
options of *: could not read status line: connection was closed by http://codesmith.googlecode.com
```

I have tried to disable firewall and antivirus on the VM, set the connection to NAT for the VM, still it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is a proxy issue.  What happens when you switch the URL to HTTPS?

```
https://codesmith.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

Note - you have to have write access to connect via https.  If it works via https, then it's a proxy issue.  See http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#proxy

To further troubleshoot, you can try to do a checkout from these URLs:

```
http://svn.collab.net:81/repos/svn/trunk/
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/
```

Collab.net listens on port 81 as well as port 80 to help people bypass proxies.  Additionally, their https server doesn't require authentication.

Comment: I can't see a replacement for the proxy-bypass port 81 listener since the move to ASF.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem on my server and it turned out to be HTTP/HTTPS issues on the server side. Is it possible your ISP or network is using an invisible HTTP proxy?

More importantly, does it work outside of the VM? Then at least you can narrow it down to a VM setting or your connection. Perhaps you could also try SVN CHECKOUT from the command line inside the VM on the off chance it's a Tortise issue.

Here is something you can run to see if a hidden proxy is messing with your connection: http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/

Answer (score 0):

If you add that url to your browser, do you get the same data in the VM and outside?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly question, but have you configured the proxy (if you need one)? It doesn't use the IE settings, but is on the TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Network page.

(sorry if you've thought of this, but the question didn't state)

Comment: Yup, I have thought of this, and I have tried it.. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of VM software are you running?  In VMWare, I can say from experience that certain kinds of network operations I've attempted have failed under NAT.  The layer of NAT abstraction can break things; however, when I switched to "Bridged", everything worked fine.  I suggest you try setting your NIC to "Bridged", no matter which VM software you're running.  Here's the description from VMWare's product:

> With bridged networking, the virtual
>   machine appears as an additional
>   computer on the same physical Ethernet
>   network as the host. The virtual
>   machine can then transparently use any
>   of the services available on the
>   network to which it is bridged,
>   including file servers, printers, and
>   gateways. Likewise, any physical host
>   or other virtual machine configured
>   with bridged networking can use
>   resources of that virtual machine.

Comment: Did switching to Bridged make any difference?